# Deploying only changed portions of a war to Tomcat

Tags: deployment, tomcat

I'm deploying my application to Tomcat, which currently involves uploading a ~40MB war file to a remote server.

Often the changes within the war only affect jars and static content which account for maybe 2 - 3MB's.  Is there some tooling I can integrate with my Ant script that can accurately detect the changes to the war and give me a smaller subset to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an ant task to copy the relevant portions of the app, zip them up and deploy them on the server.

Simple, but effective.